# Form validation gone wrong

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
        const form = document.getElementById('form');
    const Username = document.getElementById('name');
    const message = document.getElementById('message');

    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        checkInputs();
    });

    function checkInputs(){
        // trim to remove the whitespaces
    const UsernameValue = Username.value.trim();
    const messageValue = message.value.trim();

    if(UsernameValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(Username, 'Name cannot be blank');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(Username);
    }
    if(messageValue === ''){
        setErrorFor(message, 'Message tab cannot be blank');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(message);
    }

    }
    function setErrorFor(input, message) {
        const formControl = input.parentElement;
        const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
        formControl.className = 'name-style error';
        small.innerText = message;
    }
    
    function setSuccessFor(input) {
        const formControl = input.parentElement;
        formControl.className = 'name-style success';
    }
```

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
    <div class="form-container">
        <h1>CONTACT <span>ME</span></h1>
     <form action="" id="form">
        <div class="name">
            <label for="name"><span>N</span>ame:</label>
            <div class="name-style">
            <input type="name" id="name" class="name-input" placeholder="Enter your name" title="Please enter your name" required>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
            <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="e-mail">
            <label for="email"><span>E</span>mail:</label>
            <div class="input-style">
            <input type="email" id="email" class="email-input" placeholder="Enter email address" onkeydown="validation()" title="Please enter an email address" required>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <small id="text"></small>
        </div>
        <div class="textarea">
            <label for="message"><span>M</span>essage:</label>
            <div class="textarea-style">
                <textarea name="text-message" id="message" cols="16" rows="10" placeholder="Write a Message" title="Write your message here" required></textarea>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
            <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="form_btn">send</button>
     </form>
</div>
```

I have been trying to validate this form on the client-side using javascript but it doesn't work, When I put the inputs parentElement and class name in the seterrorfunction and setsuccessfunction which id is name-style, It still doesn't work, Please help me to correct if I am making any mistakes, I am only trying to validate the name input and the textarea,.

Comment: The user can't submit the form with empty input, so your check is not run

Comment: for one thing idk if it's only in the example but on the e-mail element you have an onkeydown action which calls a non existent function, also make sure you load the js defferd or put an on document loaded listener around your js

Comment: If i put spaces in the inputs (except email) i get : "Name cannot be blank" and "Message tab cannot be blank" so it works. I do have the error mentioned above however : `Uncaught ReferenceError: validation is not defined`

Comment: where did you put the spaces

Comment: onkeydown="validation()" in email input gives the : Uncaught ReferenceError: validation is not defined : error.